# global mini-cut algorithm which outputs exact edges

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am looking for an algorithm to find global mini-cut in a undirected graph.
I want to input a graph and algorithm output minimum number of the edges by cutting them the given graph can be partitioned into two parts.

Here is requirement:

1. find exact edges, not only their number.
2. the min-cut edges should compute with 100% correctly.
3. it is an undirected graph.
4. the algorithm shall terminate by indicating it found the answer or not found the answer.

I searched some articles on Internet and find out that Karger's minimum cut algorithm is randomized one, its output maybe be  not the exact min-cuts. I don't algorithm like that.
I want to  compute exact edges(I need to know which edges they are) whose number is the smallest.

I would like to hear some advice, while I am looking for such algorithms.
It would be great if your advice comes with introduction to the algorithm with example codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using max flow algorithm, when we calculate the max-flow of a graph the edges that are saturated when the algorithm finishes are part of the min-cut. You can read more about the [Max flow Min cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) . Calculating the max flow is a fairly standard problem, there are a lot of polynomial time solutions available for that problem you can read more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions).

So to summarize the algorithm, we first find the max flow of the graph, then the edges in the min cut are the ones where the flow on the edge is equal to the capacity of that edge (those edges that have been saturated).

So one of the ways to solve the max flow problem is using the [Ford Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm), it finds augmenting path in the graph, then using the minimum edge in the augmenting path tries to saturate that augmenting path, it repeats this process untill no augmenting path's are left.

To find the augmenting path we can either do a Depth first Search or  a Breadth First Search. The Edmonds Karp's algorithm finds an augmenting path by using a simple Breadth first Search.

I have written c++ code below to find the max flow and min cut, the code to find max flow is taken from the book "Competetive Programming by Steven Halim".

Also note that since the graph is undirected all the edges that the min cut function print's would be twice as it prints `a -- b` and `b -- a`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<utility>

#define MAXX 100
#define INF 1e9

using namespace std;

int s, t, flow, n, dist[MAXX], par[MAXX], AdjMat[MAXX][MAXX];  //Adjacency Matrix graph
vector< pair<int, int> > G[MAXX];   //adjacency list graph

void minCut(){
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < G[i].size();j++){
            int v = G[i][j].first;
            if(AdjMat[i][v] == 0){  //saturated edges
                cout << i << " " << v << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

void augmentPath(int v, int minEdge){
    if(v == s){ flow = minEdge;return; }
    else if(par[v] != -1){
        augmentPath(par[v], min(minEdge, AdjMat[par[v]][v]));
        AdjMat[par[v]][v] -= flow;  //forward edges
        AdjMat[v][par[v]] += flow;  //backward edges
    }
}

void EdmondsKarp(){
    int max_flow = 0;
    for(int i= 0;i < n;i++) dist[i] = -1, par[i] = -1;
    while(1){
        flow = 0;
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(s);dist[s] = 0;
        while(!q.empty()){
            int u = q.front();q.pop();
            if(u == t) break;
            for(int i = 0;i < G[u].size();i++){
                int v = G[u][i].first;
                if(AdjMat[u][v] > 0 && dist[v] == -1){
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + 1;
                    q.push(v);
                    par[v] = u;
                }
            }
        }
        augmentPath(t, INF);
        if(flow == 0) break;    //Max flow reached, now we have saturated edges that form the min cut
        max_flow += flow;
    }
}

int main(){
    //Create the graph here, both as an adjacency list and adjacency matrix
    //also mark the source i.e "s" and sink "t", before calling max flow.

    return 0;
}
```